Check a physical state of a mouse button?
I'm currently using a workaround script for burst fire using the "p" key of the keyboard because I want to use the left mouse click to shoot in auto/burst mode, for this i call the action with EVENT == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED and arg == 1  and IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
So, i'm wondering if there is an alternative to only call and use the same button (mouse button 1 , LMB) to call and execute the script instead of "p" button. I've read a suggestion to use a "fake button press" variable but i've not been able to make it work.
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
  -------------------------------------------------------
  OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
  -------------------------------------------------------
  
    --- Autoclicker/bind "p" fire ---
    if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then
        if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
            repeat
                PressKey("p")
                Sleep(1)
                ReleaseKey("p")
                Sleep(75)
                PressKey("p")
                Sleep(1)
                ReleaseKey("p")
                Sleep(75)
                PressKey("p")
                Sleep(1)
                ReleaseKey("p")
                Sleep(150)
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
            --------------------------------------
            OutputLogMessage("Burst fire shoot\n")
            --------------------------------------
        end
    else
        if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
            PressKey("p")
        elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 1 then
            ReleaseKey("p")
            ---------------------------------------
            OutputLogMessage("Normal fire shoot\n")
            ---------------------------------------
        end
    end

For some reason this script also uses to freeze and bug all Logitech ghub program after a while when tabbing between desktop and the game. I'm not sure if it is because of the program itself or the script is not optimized/done correctly.


For some reason this script also uses to freeze and bug all Logitech ghub program after a while when tabbing between desktop and the game.

Try avoiding long sleep by using InterruptableSleep for polling LMB (instead of Sleep) and don't forget to release LMB before switching from the game to desktop.
local exit

local function InterruptableSleep(ms)
   if not exit then
      local tm = GetRunningTime() + ms
      repeat
         Sleep(1)
         exit = not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) 
      until exit or GetRunningTime() >= tm
   end
   return exit
end

EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
  -------------------------------------------------------
  OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
  -------------------------------------------------------
  
    --- Autoclicker/bind "p" fire ---
    if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then
        if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
            exit = false
            repeat
                PressKey("p")
                Sleep(1)
                ReleaseKey("p")
                if InterruptableSleep(75) then break end
                PressKey("p")
                Sleep(1)
                ReleaseKey("p")
                if InterruptableSleep(75) then break end
                PressKey("p")
                Sleep(1)
                ReleaseKey("p")
                if InterruptableSleep(150) then break end
            until false
            --------------------------------------
            OutputLogMessage("Burst fire shoot\n")
            --------------------------------------
        end
    else
        if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
            PressKey("p")
        elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 1 then
            ReleaseKey("p")
            ---------------------------------------
            OutputLogMessage("Normal fire shoot\n")
            ---------------------------------------
        end
    end



if there is an alternative to only call and use the same button (mouse button 1 , LMB) to call and execute the script instead of "p" button

It is impossible to both simulate PressMouseButton(1) and monitor IsMouseButtonPressed(1) at the same time.  Choose one of the two.
